# React Native onPressIn

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs, callback, react-native

So I am currently writing a React Native app, and have run into a small problem.  When I press and hold a button, I want to run a function repeatedly until the button press is released. Here is the function:

```
onButtonPressIn() {
  this.setState({pressStatus: true})
  recording = true

    let myCallBack = () => {
    setTimeout(this.executeFunction.bind(this), 50)
  }
  if (recording === true) {
    myCallBack()
  }
}
```

I know that the if statement only executes the code once, but every other method I tried did not work at all, and a while loop in place of the if statement did not allow anything to run. It is also worth noting that when my button is released, recording is set equal to false (it is declared as a global variable in the beginning of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your whole component, I assume this should help you to get started:

```
let recording = false
let ivRecording
...
onButtonPressIn() {
  this.setState({pressStatus: true})
  recording = true
  ivRecording = setInterval(() => this.executeFunction(), 50)
}
...
onButtonPressRelease() {
  this.setState({pressStatus: false})
  recording = false
  clearInterval(ivRecording)
}
```